# No data returned with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here's the relevant piece of my PHP code:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//get values from AJAX
$whereCategory = isset($_GET['cat_code'])? "{$_GET['cat_code']}" : '';
$sortvalue = isset($_GET['sortvalue'])? "{$_GET['sortvalue']}" : '';
$sortorder = isset($_GET['sortorder'])? "{$_GET['sortorder']}" : '';

$sql = "select * from  {$table} where cat_code = ':cat_code' order by ':sortvalue' ':sortorder';";
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY) );
$stmt2->execute(array(':cat_code' => $whereCategory,':sortvalue' => $sortvalue, ':sortorder' => $sortorder));
$result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

If I `var_dump` the variables `$where_category`,`$sortorder`, and `$sortvalue`, they are all what I expect and the correct data that would need to be passed in the query. I've tried the query directly without PDO just substituting in the correct variables and I get back what I want, but apparently I'm not sending the variables correctly with my PDO methods (such as they are).

I'm getting no errors back, but no data returned either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you error reporting is on.

Comment: fyi: placeholders doesn't need quotes

Comment: why do you use {} for your values?

Comment: @Ghost Where do I not need quotes?

Comment: @niyou Not sure where you mean. I've inherited most of this, so trying to figure out what's happening and by no means a PHP or PDO expert.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed Error reporting is on.

Comment: Is `$table` defined properly?

Comment: @jonmrich in your PDO statement, your `...catcode = ':cat_code'...` in the SQL does *not* need to be encased in quote marks, so instead use `...cat_code = :cat_code ...` , for all your placeholders (placeholders are the colon variables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, named placeholders doesn't need to be quoted, so ditch those.

Secondly, you cannot bind identifiers (table/columns/DESC/ASC) You could only whitelist those.

Third, don't mix `->query()` and `->execute()`. Use `->execute()` alone:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//get values from AJAX
if(isset($_GET['cat_code'], $_GET['sortvalue'], $_GET['sortorder'])) {

    $whereCategory = $_GET['cat_code'];
    $sortvalue = $_GET['sortvalue'];
    $sortorder = $_GET['sortorder'];

    // super simple filtering
    $default_tables = array('table1', 'table2', 'table3');
    $default_columns = array('column1', 'column2', 'column3');
    in_array(needle, haystack)
    if(
        in_array($table, $default_tables) &&
        in_array($sortvalue, $default_columns) &&
        in_array($sortorder, array('ASC', 'DESC'))
    ) {
        // good to go

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table where cat_code = :cat_code ORDER BY $sortvalue $sortorder";
        $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt2->execute(array(':cat_code' => $whereCategory));
        echo json_encode($stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

    } else {
        // did not satisfy condition
    }

}
```

Sidenote: Those default tables and columns are just examples, you'll need to populate and correspond it into yours. You could create your own method/function which creates a map with tables with their corresponding columns if you really want to be sure of it.

Comment: This was hugely helpful and makes total sense. `$table` is "clean", as I'm getting this from my database, `$sort_order` is easy enough to check. `$sort_value` is a little trickier since I need to pull from a database table. I'm going to post another question about that. I'm close, but not quite.

Comment: @jonmrich its okay if its not a user input but, if you want to be sure, you'll have to do those, glad this helped.

Comment: It's definitely a user input, so I have to make sure it's on the whitelist. Here's my new question, where I'm stuck making an array to test against: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825919/parse-mysql-query-results-and-form-array-for-if-else

Answer (score 1):

Change this -

```
$result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to this -

```
$result = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You're trying to run the query again when all you need to do is grab the results.

Comment: Just made this change and no difference.

Comment: Check your error logs @jonmrich and add some error checking to your PDO. Your not catching errors.

Answer (score 1):

The query you are running is against a prepared statement which is incorrect, removing the query and assigning the result from the execute statement will work. There's also quite a few other problems in your php. Also using the input directly from the user such as the table (which appears to be undefined in this code snippet), sort order and sort value leaves you open to sql injection.

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//get values from AJAX
$whereCategory = isset($_GET['cat_code'])? $_GET['cat_code'] : '';
$sortvalue = isset($_GET['sortvalue'])? $_GET['sortvalue'] : '';
$sortorder = isset($_GET['sortorder'])? $_GET['sortorder'] : '';

/** you cannot use prepared statements for doing the order by */
$sql = "select * from $table where cat_code = :cat_code order by $sortvalue $sortorder;";
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY) );
$query = $stmt2->execute(['cat_code' => $whereCategory]);
/** below line isn't needed because above on deals with it */
//$dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $query->fetchAll();
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Didn't realize you can't do prepared statements for order by. That was the problem. I do need to get these values from the user, so is there another way I can "clean" these before passing them?

Comment: you could define the values that are accepted rather allowing it to be sorted by anything. For instance lets say you didn't index the column that's being sorted on the query will perform poorly.

Comment: as for the sortorder that one is an easier challenge to solve `$sortorder = isset($_GET['sortorder']) && strtoupper($_GET['sortorder']) === 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';`

Answer (score 0):

try without quotes:

```
$sql = "select * from  {$table} where cat_code = :cat_code order by :sortvalue :sortorder;";
```

Comment: `':sortvalue'` is used in the query to say what the query should be sorted by (i.e., what column), so I need that in there.

Comment: This gave me a fatal error on the first `$stmt2` line: "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/live/php/all_get_login.php:24"

Answer (score -1):

Use Like this

```
$result = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```