# Parse mySQL query results and form array for if/else

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to get all the values in one column in a table so I can create a whitelist for another query. Here's how I'm getting that:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("select GROUP_CONCAT( cohort_id SEPARATOR ',') as cohort_id from ( select distinct cohort_id from table_cohorts) as m"); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$avails = json_encode($row);
```

If I `var_dump` `$avails`, I get this:

`string(125) "{"cohort_id":"national_percent,database_percent,cohort_1,cohort_2","0":"national_percent,database_percent,cohort_1,cohort_2"}"`

The stuff with "cohort_id" is what I want. I need to form an array so I can drop it in something like this:

`(in_array($sortvalue, $arrayofpossibleoptions))` //`$sortvalue` comes from AJAX

How can I get this in the right format? One further wrinkle, I need to add one additional value to the `$arrayofpossibleoptions`  or something like this, but not sure what the proper syntax is:

`(in_array($sortvalue, $arrayofpossibleoptions || 'another' ))`

If I `var_dump` `$row`, I get this:

```
array(2) {
  ["cohort_id"]=>
  string(51) "national_percent,database_percent,cohort_1,cohort_2"
  [0]=>
  string(51) "national_percent,database_percent,cohort_1,cohort_2"
}
```

Comment: Give an example array you want to achieve

Comment: sounds like you need to explode() that value into an array, which begs the question of why you're doing a `group_concat()` inside the query, since you're just going to be UNDOING that concatting anyways. kill the concat, do a normal query, fetch in a loop, and build your array in php.

Comment: is this in conjuction to what you're trying to do earlier in the whitelisting? you don't need to have that in json string form if its an array already in PHP, (or you need this in your client-side as well?) anyway, its a bad idea all the way just like Marc eloquently stated.

Comment: @MarcB Got it. Using some inherited code, that obviously doesn't apply. I changed to this, but it only gives me the first value from the query, not all of them. 

`$stmt = $dbh->prepare("select cohort_id as cohort_id from ( select distinct cohort_id from table_cohorts) as m"); `

`$stmt->execute(); `

`$row = $stmt->fetch();`

`$categories = explode(",",$row["cohort_id"]);`

Comment: ->fetch() only fetches one row. do a `while($row = ->fetch()) { $data[] = explode(...) }` to build a new array of your exploded stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this data to be loaded into `in_array`, then it should be in an array form, you can't use a json string.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT cohort_id FROM table_cohorts'); 
$stmt->execute();
$cohort_ids = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $cohort_ids[] = $row['cohort_id'];
}

if(in_array($user_input, $cohort_ids)) {
    // do the rest
} else {
    // oops your input is not any of those
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I actually figured out a way to do it before your post, but it was WAY less elegant, so yours works perfectly. Thanks.